# Es posible trabajar código en el servidor desde XAMPP

Tags: php, javascript, ftp, host

¿Es posible vincular el host donde esta mi proyecto con mi editor de codigo?; es decir, existe alguna manera en la que trabajando desde mi XAMPP en Visual studio, Sublime, etc pueda guardar los archivos y al mismo tiempo estos se actualicen en el servidor donde tengo alojado el proyecto?

Comment: Es mala idea editar y publicar directamente al servidor de producción, ¿qué pasa si hay errores? Realiza las modificaciones en local, prueba y, cuando veas que todo funciona bien, subes al servidor.

Answer (score 0):

En el caso de [Sublime Text](https://www.sublimetext.com/3) existe un plugin llamado [SFTP](https://codexns.io/products/sftp_for_sublime) para tener un ***FTP*** persistente, con él se puede editar directamente en el hosting, pero ya no tendría sentido que tengas ***Xampp*** pues lo editado estará en tu hosting.

Deberías explicar para qué deseas realizar ese tipo de conexión.
Al utilizar ***GitHub***, por ejemplo, las pruebas las realizas en tu equipo con ***Xampp*** (por ejemplo) y luego se suben directamente al repositorio de ***GitHub***. Pero algo así no conozco para un hosting.

Comment: Bueno, igual y especificamente al XAMPP no es necesario. Tienes razon con el promer parrafo que no seria necesario, pero lo que busco es que mientras programo en mi editor, se actualice el proyecto en el hosting

Answer (score 0):

@aguevara33, Si se puede realizar la instalación y ocupar con Xampp o Apache Server por ejemplo, pero de todas maneras tendrías que instalar el modulo **mod_wsgi**.
 Pero debes tener en cuenta que en la documentación oficial de Django advierten que no es seguro poner los proyectos en la carpeta **xampp/htdocs** como se hace con los Frameworks de Php por ejemplo.

> [image: Django Warning!]

En la sección 3.1.2 de la documentación que se puede descargar en formato PDF explican como instalar Django con **Apache y mod_wsgi**

> Esta información la puedes encontrar en la pagina oficial de Django
> https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/topics/install/

Saludos